# telerik.web.mvc unable to load on visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor, telerik

I used to use visual studio 2012 and in an area telerik was configured and worked correctly.

after changing visual studio to 2013 this error occurred after each page is rendering.

```
 Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Line 50:     @(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar())
```

web.config structure for this area view is:

<system.web.webPages.razor>














</system.web.webPages.razor>

i don't wanna change telerik to kendo.ui
what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web.config of the view

```
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="Bazidan.MVC.UI" />
    <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI"/>
    <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
    <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
  </namespaces>
```